# Ajax success and error handlers not working with nodejs

Tags: node.js, ajax

For some reason, the success and error handlers of my ajax request is not working as expected.

My node server performs correctly and gives me the right results, but whatever is in the error section of my ajax request executes regardless.

I checked other posts and they seem to be doing the same thing I am. I  can't figure out what's happening.

My ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: path,
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: items,
        success: function(response)
        {

            alert('Tweety Logs sent successfully.')
        },
        error: function(err)
        {

            alert('Tweety Logs not sent.')
        }
});
```

The function in my server:

```
function log(req,res)
{
  var breed = req.body.breed;
  var list = req.body.logs;
  try {
    fs.appendFileSync("Logs/log.dat", JSON.stringify(breed) + "logs:\r\n");
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
      fs.appendFileSync("Logs/log.dat", JSON.stringify(list[i])  + "\r\n");
      console.log('Added to Logs/log.dat - ' + JSON.stringify(list[i]));
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log('Error writing to the file: ' + err.message)
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
}
```

The error bit of ajax gets called everytime even if it's successful.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add console log in your server code it it won't be a json response. You need to add json data to your res.send instead of console.log

And remove console.logs

Comment: But I need to show output in the cmd as part of my assignment. So i need to use console.log

Comment: I'm using res.sendStatus though. Shouldn't this work?

Comment: You are sending status code as 200 that does not works as your response as not Json your UI code accepts only json response

Answer (score 0):

It been awhile  I  used Ajax last but you can try out axios or fetch they will make your life much easier. 
Axios handle error better by using the catch block.

Check this links for more help and details. 
https://alligator.io/js/axios-vanilla-js/
https://alligator.io/js/fetch-api/

Comment: I wish this were the case. But this is my university assignment. I can't use things that have not been taught